CoreData re-encrypt string property
I'm using Core Data in my iOS application and I have one property that is encrypted using ValueTransformer:
class EncryptedStringTransformer: ValueTransformer {
private var encryptionKey: String

init(encryptionKey: String) {
    self.encryptionKey = encryptionKey
    super.init()
}

override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
    return NSData.self
}

override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let string = value as? String,
          let data = string.data(using: .utf8),
          let encryptedData = EncryptionUtils.aes256EncryptData(data, withKey: encryptionKey) else { return nil }
    return encryptedData
}

override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let encryptedData = value as? Data,
          let decryptedData = EncryptionUtils.aes256DecryptData(encryptedData, withKey: encryptionKey) else { return nil }
    return String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8)
}

func updateEncryptionKey(newKey: String) {
    self.encryptionKey = newKey
}
}

The encrypted property is String:
@NSManaged public var message: String?
and it set in the CoreData model as Transformable
the encryption is based on the user password that can be changed, if the user updates the password I want to re-encrypt the property, I try to do it using this function:
func reEncryptDataWithNewPassword(oldPassword: String, newPassword: String) -> ReEncryptDBStatus {
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest()
guard let messages = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) else {
    return .failed
}

guard !messages.isEmpty else {
    return .success
}

for message in messages {
    if let _ = message.message {
        message.message = message.message
    }
}

ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(EncryptedStringTransformer(encryptionKey: newPassword), forName: .encryptedStringTransformer)

do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    return .failed
}

return .success
}

The problem is that trying context.save() does not force the DB to update the property, and transformedValue in EncryptedStringTransformer is not called when I call context.save().
Any idea what can be the problem?

Info: I assume, your user's password is stored in the KeyChain. The encrypted string thus has no more security than the access to the key chain. You might also directly store your string into the key chain instead of CoreData. You also might consider to add an additional layer of security on top of the KeyChain  by requiring Local Authentication: when the app needs access to the secure item it will then authenticate the user via TouchID, FaceID or Passcode. The resulting LAContext which grants access can be reused or invalidated.

May be problem with name? Doesn't see how .encryptedStringTransformer declared? May be use @objc and declare explicit name
